# Is there a way to "unlearn" skills in Heroes III?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

In Heroes of Might and Magic III your heroes gain skills as they level up. When you level up, you will be presented with two options for skills, one of which you can opt to learn. There are three tiers of each skill - Basic, Advanced and Expert.

Another way to gain skills is to get them from random dwellings on the map such as a Seer's Hut.

Because I don't look at what I'm doing and click anything that says unvisited, I always end up ruining my hero by learning a skill like "Scouting" or "Eagle Eye" from a random dwelling.

Is there a way I can discard these skills?

Comment: Erf. I know there's a neutral building to reset hero skills, but I think that might have been Heroes V...

Comment: Yes, this building is in Heroes V

Comment: What's so bad about Scouting?  It can save you a lot of movement points.

Comment: @Kyralessa It's no Expert Air Magic, though.

Comment: @Kyralessa, The problem is that one hero can only have up to 8 skills.

Comment: According to the answer on [my question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/313546/168837), the map structure 'Market of Time' was supposed to do this.

Comment: Not a valid answer, but you can edit your heroes in memory, discarding their skills or changing them to different ones. And yes, that's pure cheating ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there's no way of unlearning skills in Heroes III. At least not in the core version of the game, WoG has introduced the Arcane Towers that allow a hero to redistribute his or her primary skill points but not secondary skill points. ([Wake of Gods](http://www.strategyplanet.com/homm/wog/New%20WoG%20Features.pdf))

A good tactic that I use is to visit Witch Huts and similar dwellings with my secondary hero to avoid messing up my primary heros's skills.

Comment: By secondary hero do you mean autosave?

Comment: @Stoz In both multiplayer and single player, it is quite typical to use extra heroes to scout the area with, before deciding where to move the bulk of your army that's equipped to "primary" or "main" heroes. Using one of these extra heroes or scouts to check the skill offered gives you information about whether it's worth going there with a main hero. This way, even if the skill is crap you are essentially losing nothing, as the scouts are not expected to level up very much if at all.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't.

A standard tactic is to save your game before approaching a Witch Hut and reload if you don't want that particular skill.  My autosave has saved me a few times.

Comment: You can not save/load in multiplayer :(

Comment: @Mentoliptus, Good point, but do people still play multiplayer Heroes3?

Comment: We play it mostly in hot seat mode :)

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, we do play online. But we are using HD mod + HotA expansion, because they fix a lot of original annoying bugs and gameplay balance issues and make everything a lot more comfortable and reduce tedious stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Probe dwelling with secondary / non-important hero beforehand.

To avoid situation when you need to choose between two bad skills when hero levels up - always leave few skill on basic/advanced. That way useless skill can be avoided as **if there is at least one skill is non-extert it will be present in the choise giving you an opportunity to avoid an alternative new useles skill**.