# What is the Market of Time supposed to do?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

One of the original scenarios in Heroes of Might and Magic III, Titan's Winter, contains a strange map structure on the final piece of land, the "Market of Time". This is the only scenario containing this structure, and when I visit it with my hero, nothing happens. What is it supposed to do, or is it just something akin to an Easter Egg?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to several different wiki pages ([like this](http://heroes.thelazy.net/wiki/Market_of_Time)) it was supposed to allow heroes to unlearn skills:

> Market of Time appears to have no function, however it was intended to let visiting
>   heroes to unlearn secondary skills.

Comment: Thanks. 'It was supposed to' - does that mean there are actual versions of the game where this was possible, or is it just an oversight and should it have been deleted?

Comment: @Glorfindel looks like it works that way in fan-made mod In the Wake of Gods (or WOG)